# Having trouble reading a simple recursion code(JAVA)

Tags: java, debugging, recursion

Hello I am studying recursion and having trouble reading the following code below

```
public class MysteryClass {

/**
 * Mystery method that performs a function recursively.
 *
 * @param x an integer > 0
 * @param y an integer > 0 and < x
 * prints result
 */
    public static void mysteryMethod(int x, int y) {
        if (x == 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            mysteryMethod(x / y, y);
            System.out.print(x % y);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mysteryMethod(13,2);
    }
}
```

I had two possible solutions(and realized both are wrong)

**Solution 1**

1. x = 13, y = 2, print(13 % 2) which is 1
2. x = 6 , y = 2, print( 6 % 2) which is 0
3. x = 3 , y = 2, print( 3 % 2) which is 1
4. x = 1 , y = 2, print( 1 % 2) which is 1
5. x = 0 , y = 2, since x == 0, return nothing and stop recursion.

therefore 1011

**Solution 2**

1. x = 13, y = 2, mysteryMethod(13 / 2, 2) which is mysteryMethod(6, 2) since 6 != 0 go to next step
2. x = 6 , y = 2, mysteryMethod(6 / 2, 2) which is mysteryMethod(3, 2) since 3 != 0 go to next step
3. x = 3 , y = 2, mysteryMethod(3 / 2, 2) which is mysteryMethod(1, 2) since 1 != 0 go to next step
4. x = 1 , y = 2, mysteryMethod(1 / 2, 2) which is mysteryMethod(0, 2) since 0 == 0 return nothing and stop recursion.

therefore return nothing

**but the correct answer was 1101**

**Can anyone have a look at the code and explain me why 1101 is the correct answer and why my solutions are wrong?**

Comment: When you follow the steps in your first interpretation, what do you conclude is being printed? Why?

Comment: First of all, x = 13 and y = 2. since x is not equal to, I would move on to the else statement. From the else statement, it would be like '''mysteryMethod(13 / 2, 2)''' which is equals to mysteryMethod(6,2). I do not know what to do next. Should I just go back to the if statemetns and check if 6 is equal to 0 or print(13 % 2) which is 1?

Comment: Okay, so. In your first interpretation, you say: "x = 13, y = 2, print(13 % 2) which is 1". So you are saying that a `1` will be printed, yes? Now, when you look at all of the things **that are printed**, what are you expecting to see? Now, look at "the correct answer". Do you see a simple way to describe how they are different? Now, think about which happens first: making the recursive call, or printing the modulo result. Does it make sense to you that this would impact on the output?

Comment: When I compare the answer I got(1011) and the correct answer(1101), I can tell my answer is printed backward. In my understanding, recursive call happens first and then we print the modulo result. Does that mean we should do Mm(13, 2) Mm(6, 2) Mm(3, 2) Mm(1, 2)  then print backword?

Comment: Looks like you understand now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you did the recursion then print the number, you should print the number then recursion, that is:

```
public static void mysteryMethod(int x, int y) {
        if (x == 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.print(x % y);//exchange the position of the two lines of code
            mysteryMethod(x / y, y);
        }
    }
```

In you code, you're printing the number backward...

Comment: The code was provided from my class and I assume they do not have any error. And I am having problem reading the code. The answer should be 1101 but whenever I trace the code I get 1011 instead of 1101.

Comment: @JeffKim Ok... How do you want the number to be printed?

Comment: I am having problem interpreting the code. The answer my instructor provided is 1101 but I am keep getting 1011 and I cannot figure out why the answer should be 1101.

Comment: @JeffKim that is because it prints the number from step 5(from solution 1) then prints the number from step 4, and so on...